# Modify column data type from Numeric to Character using System i Navigator

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to modify the column data type from NUMERIC (1,0) to CHARACTER (1) using System i Navigator (AS400) but I get a message error :

```
SQL State: 42837
Message: [SQL0190] Attributes of column Col1 in Table1 in Library1 not
compatible. Cause . . . . . :   The attributes specified for column Col1 in 
Table1 in Library1 are not compatible with the attributes of the existing 
column. Either the data type, the length, or the clause is not valid. -- A 
numeric column cannot be changed to a type that is not numeric. -- A 
character column cannot be changed to a DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP, or a numeric 
column. --
```

Is there anyway to update the data type of the column without having to delete it and add it again?
I could do it but the problem is that I will have to remove all the columns that are defined after in order to add them in the same order.
This table doesn't contain data for now.

Comment: Please provide the existing data type with precision/scale as well as the specific target attributes. Essentially, only one attribute should be changed at a time, so we need to see them all including lengths in order to give the right answer.

Comment: Thought I remembered making the same kind of conversion in the past, but it's not allowed. You'll need to add a CHAR(1) column, UPDATE the converted value, then drop the NUMERIC(1,0) column. Or recreate the table.

Comment: Please see my answered post, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found two alternatives to fix this issue without having to manually recreate the table:

1. Right-click the table, click on Generate SQL... update the column data type, delete the table and then run the sql.
2. Rename the table, create a new one, right-click the table and click on Definition. Click the Browse... button and select all the columns from the renamed table. Before saving, change the datatype (or whatever you need)

Comment: Yep, you can't change the type.  You'll have to create a new table, then use SQL or CPYF FMTOPT(*NOCHK) to copy the data over.